# .htaccess/.htpasswd Protection for file doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, .htpasswd

I have a problem for which I have not yet found any solution.
I want to make a file a accessible via .htaccess/.htpasswd. So I created this file and put it into a subfolder at my we bapplication:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Username"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

The access protection for the subfolder works, but not for the file in this.

I'm looking forward for any hint or help.

Thx!

Comment: BasicAuth is notorious for caching credentials. Make sure you are using a clean browser session...e.g. Incognito for Chrome, InPrivate for IE. Then re-test hitting the file directly. If its contained in an AUTH protected directory, you should be challenged to authenticate. Your settings look fine.

Comment: Also, to clarify, those auth settings should be in your .htaccess file and that .htaccess file should be in the same subfolder as the file you want to protect.

Comment: Hi Brandon

Thx for your reply.
Private session and access from 2 other webconnections unfortunately does not work well. I can readt the file without any protection. 
"<FilesMatch "file.php">" doesn't work too.

The .htaccess is located in the same folder as the to be protected file.

Comment: If you're using <File or <FileMatch, then that is likely what's causing the conflicting behavior (are you using access control? e.g. Allow, Deny, Satisfy..etc.). If you're just wanting to auth protect a directory and the files in it, you only need the Auth settings you noted, you do not need File based access control. If you do need to further define access control, then make sure you use Satisfy ALL. If that doesn't help, paste in your full .htaccess contents.

Comment: It's strange. For .txt files, the protection works. For .php files not.